# Import - Module not found

Tags: python, import, module, pip

I am very new, all help much appreciated.

In trying to learn Python, I am repeatedly coming up with an issue I don't know how to solve.

Each time I try to call a module via the "import" function I am getting the following error message -

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

However, when I run the command line install prompt, I am told that the request is already satisfied (i.e. it should already be installed). I haven't saved anything in a bespoke location (or at least, I am not aware I have!).

```
C:\Users\chris>pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2020.12.5)
```

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed or maybe you are using virtualenv?

Comment: Hi - I don't use windows but I believe sometimes when installing python if you don't select 'add to path' there can be issues with python finding the modules. You could look at Anaconda as it is is generally quite user friendly for beginners.

Comment: first check versions `pip -V` and `python -V` to see if you use correct `pip` for your `python`. Every Python has own `pip` which installs modules in different folder (pythons don't share modules) - and you may install module for one Python but you run code with different Python. Similar problem was many times on Stackoverflow. The simple solution is to use `python -m pip install ...` to run `pip` for correct `python`.

Answer (score 0):

try this command

`py -3.9 -m pip install requests`

You can refer the official documentation https://docs.python.org/3/installing/